# How to know, service worker is retrieving data from cache?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, browser-cache, service-worker

[image]

I'm trying to get data from cache inside a service worker. But how do I know it's fetching the data properly?
The initiator **(index):-Infinity**, indicates it comes from **cache**?

Comment: are you using webpack or source maps too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome 55 (and possibly earlier versions) the Size column hints what type of cache (disk, memory or service worker) was used when fetching the file.

[image: dev-tools-cache]

Comment: that does not answer the question which is "what does -Infinity" mean?